# TypeError: userDetails.findAll is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using localhost MongoDB. While I am running the node app.js
 that time shows connecting to the server. when I am going to test the API in postman at the time getting an error like `userDetails.findAll` is not a function.

```
 Model.js:

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema =mongoose.Schema;

    const userSchema=new Schema({
        userId:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        userName:
        {
            type:String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        userPwd:
        {
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        is_active:{
            type:Boolean,
            required:true
        }
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model("usersDetails",userSchema);



     controller.js:

        var userDetails = require('../userDetailsModels/userDetails-model');

        var getUserDetails = (req, res) => {
            userDetails.findAll({
                where: {
                    is_active:true
                }
            }).then(userAll => {
                res.status(200).json(userAll);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err,
                    message: 'Something went wrong'
                });
            });
        };

        module.exports ={
            getUserDetails:getUserDetails
        }


router.js:

var express = require('express');
var usersRouter = express.Router();

var UserDetailsController = require('../userDetailsControllers/userDetails-controller');

usersRouter.route('/getUsers/all').get(UserDetailsController.getUserDetails);

module.exports = usersRouter;
```

The above is model.js, controller.js and router.js.I don't know where I did mistake in this code. Every time I am getting userDetails.findAll is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You should mention `mongoose` version.

Please check available methods from mongoose document site from [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

And, Please check how to use `where` from [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.where):

> There is no any method available like `findAll`.

What you can do is use `find` method that will return all matched document as below:

```
userDetails.find().where('is_active').equals(true)
.exec(function(error, userAll) {
  if(error){
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err,
      message: 'Something went wrong'
    });
  } else {
    res.status(200).json(userAll);
  }
});
```

Hope this may help you..!!

Comment: I didn't get any error .But in postman while sending api i am getting could not get any response

Comment: There must not be any user then with `is_active  == true`

Comment: What is data type of `is_Active` in mongoDB?

Comment: is_active:Boolean and data is available for is_active:true

Comment: Check the updated answer. You are using `where` clause in wrong way

Comment: I am able to fetch data correctly, Seems your code has some issue. Try to put `console.log(userAll)` just below of exec and let me know the output

Comment: now i soved the issues.but i stored datas in mongodb.when i call the datas from using api that time shows empty data in postman

Comment: You muat have some minor issue. Anyways, the outcome is, you can use find method of mongoose to retrieve all matched data.

Comment: issue in db collection name.i found solution for this one